# Is the polynomial determinant of linear independent polynomials irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, determinant

Let $m,n\in\mathbb N $, and let  $A=[p_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^m$ be a matrix of irreducible polynomials where $p_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

Depending on $m$ and $n$, prove or disprove that if $p_{ij}$ are linearly independent polynomials then the determinant polynomial $|A|$ is irreducible over reals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean?.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this holds only for trivial reasons. Namely, every polynomial over $\mathbb R $ of a degree $\gt 2$ is reducible. Thus, for $m \gt 1$ you cannot find enough linearly independent polynomias. For $m=1$ the claim is trivial. Are you sure there is no mistake in the setting of this problem?

Comment: The polynomial $x^2+1$ is not reducible over reals. Yes, this  the idea I will change the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Are $m $ (size of the matrix) and $n $ (number of variables in the polynomials) related?

Comment: No, $m$ and $n$  are not related. I am trying to understand the zero-locus of the polynomial determinant in a general. I believe the claim holds true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m = 2$, $n = 1$, there is a counterexample.

$$  \det \begin{pmatrix} x^2 + 1 & x^2 + 2 \\ x^2 + 3 & x^2 + 5 \end{pmatrix}  = x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)  \text{.}  $$

This is also a counterexample for the problem as stated for $n > 1$ (since there is no requirement that all $n$ variables be used).

For $m= 3$, $n>1$, there are counterexamples.

$$  \det \begin{pmatrix} x^2 + 1 & x^2 + 2 & x^2 + 4 \\ x^2 + 3 & x^2 + 5 & x^2 + 7 \\ x^2 + 6 & x^2 + 9 & x^2 +10  \end{pmatrix}  = x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)  \text{.}  $$

$$  \det \begin{pmatrix} x^2 + 1 & x^2 + 2 & x^2 + 4 \\ x^2 + 3 & x^2 + 5 & x^2 + 7 \\ x^2 + 6 & x^2 + 9 & x^2 +12  \end{pmatrix}  = x^2 - 3 = (x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3})  \text{.}  $$

The claim seems somewhat dubious.  (These were not found by any sort of search, they were the second or third thing I tried for each $m$.)

Comment: Dear @Eric Towers many thanks for your answer.

Comment: But ... @Eric Towers ... $p_{ij}$ are not linearly independent in your examples, are they? You cannot find more than 3 linearly independent irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb R$, that is why I said in my comment that, for one variable, the claim may hold - for trivial reasons.

Comment: @user8734617 : I completely agree.  OP didn't say over what ring or field he wanted linear independence, so I picked one (and it was not $\mathbb{R}$, for the reason you mention).  OP's replies to your comment suggested he hadn't tried small examples, so I put some out to see what would happen.